# css stretch floating div horizontally

Tags: css, css-float, html, stretch

I'm trying to make a div with a static height and variable width. With multiple horizontal tabs. The active tab should stretch horizontally to fill the container and the inactive tabs should shrink back down to their inactive size (24px in this case).

I can't quite get it to work. The tab stretches, but too much. It bumps the tabs after it to the next line, which shoudn't happen. I can't figure out how to make this work like I want it to.

What I am trying to do can be seen at [link removed]

I'm sure that theres a way to do it, as I've seen it done before, but I can't find an example of it. Know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: please post an example. i tried your code and i still cant figure out what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a horizontal accordion?

- http://www.leigeber.com/2008/05/horizontal-javascript-accordion-menu/
- http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#fillspace

There are several examples online. It may be best to rely on Javascript to do the calculating if you want the open tab to take up all the space MINUS the width of the tabs, of the container.

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying to do. I couldn't think of what it was called. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
#navigation
{
   border: 1px solid #000000;
   height: 400px;
   margin: 10px 25px;
   padding: 0px;
   width: auto;
}
.item
{
   display: block;
   float: left;
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0px;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.item img { float: left; margin-right: 5px;}
.closed
{
   width: 10%;
}
.open
{
   width: 80%;
}

</style>

</head>

   <body>
      <div id="navigation">
         <div class="item open">
            <img src="hometab.png" alt="Home" />

            Open Tab Open Tab
         </div>
         <div class="item closed">
            <img src="hometab.png" alt="Home" />
            Open Tab Open Tab
         </div>
         <div class="item closed">
            <img src="hometab.png" alt="Home" />
            Open Tab Open Tab
         </div>

      </div>
```

Comment: See the example link. It shows better what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

How committed are you to `width:auto` on `#navigation`?

If you set the width of `#navigation` to something fixed and also set appropriate width values for `.open` then it looks pretty good.

When I was playing with your example in [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) I used 400 for `#navigation` and 350 for `.open` and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 0):

The extra items are probably being bumped to the next line because the width of your open tab is 100% - try setting it to 80% or 90%, to leave room for the extra "tabs" after it. The "closed" tabs should probably also have a percent width, which should all add together to equal 100% - the full width of their container.

Answer (score 0):

Following approach worked for me:

Let “w” be original width of the div and you want to stretch it by “x” pixels. Adding following CSS on it:

```
{
    width: (w + x) px;
    margin-left: -x/2 px
}
```

e.g. if original width is 300px and you want to stretch it by 50px, additional CSS will be:

```
{
    width: 350px;
    margin-left: -25px
}
```